# Why ORF13 and ORF14 of Bat Sars coronavirus Rp3 have no corrispondence in Sars2?

Tags: covid-19, sars-cov-2, coronavirus

I'am comparing bats coronavirus with Sars2, i.e. COVID-19. I have one question...

- one Bat Sars coronaviurs identify in GenBank as DQ071615.1 has the ORF13(28122..28415) and ORF14(28572..28784) proteins
- Sars2 identify in GenBank as MN908947_3, has range 28284..28577
  not labeled as ORF13 and the same 28734..28955 is not labeled as ORF14?

The ORF13(28122..28415) of Bat coronavirus and  PSEUDO_ORF13(28284..28577) of sars2 share 72% homology
and ORF14(28572..28784) of Bat coronavirus and  PSEUDO_ORF14(28734..28955) of sars2 share 75% homology

---

This seems one publication for ORF14 and ORF13 in Bat Viruses and relations in Sars2 [here](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/bmri/2020/7234961/)

The author say that ORF14 in Sars2 is all contained in N protein...
And ORF13 is know in that above link as ORF9B
and in that written is said ORF9B is implied in immunitary innate suppression...

Comment: Key to the answer is whether Rp3 is a Chinese bat virus ... I think the virus was originally part of this study https://science.sciencemag.org/content/310/5748/676 If you can tell me its country of origin .. if its Europe or Africa that would explain it.

Comment: i remember only i was surprised orf1ab was so different from sars2. And has in orf3 one 7 letter amminoacid chain that i was sarching in common with ebola (if i remember well)

Answer (score 1):

The virus Rp3 stands for Rhi pea isolated in China in 2004.

The trees is [here](https://jvi.asm.org/content/84/21/11336) and groups with the Bulgarian sarbecoviruses and is closely related to the African sarbecoviruses. Thus although it is a Chinese sarbecovirus is not with the "Chinease originating" clade as is SARS and Covid-19.

Thats why the more mysterious ORFs ORF13 and 14 are missing, because over notable genetic distances these genes along with ORF10 are present/absent. This is a common feature of the betacoronaviruses.

In summmary this virus is notably distance from the major human pathogenic SARS/covid-19 viruses. Thus the absence of these auxilary genes isn't really surprising.

Its the very last taxa on the SARS-related viruses clade (monophyly) and is in a different group to SARS, which is the Beta-1 clade on this most excellent paper.

---

To answer the comment. They are outgroups, basically ancestral to COVID-19 and SARS-1 clade. So they lost these genes whilst the ingroup including COVID-109 and SARS-1 retained ORF13, 14 ... but I think lost ORF10 from memory

[image]

Comment: "Thats why the more mysterious ORFs ORF13 and 14 are missing, because over notable genetic distances these genes along with ORF10 are present/absen"... the distance of what? >70% the same

Comment: 70% is a lot, post modified above.